# I have two top panels in Ubuntu for some reason

Tags: 11.10, unity, panel

My ubuntu was working fine, then I moved my computer around, and when I brought it back, I now have two top panels like so:

[image: Panel with window maximized]

The smaller bottom panel still works somewhat, so it is not just a matter of it being drawn twice. It is a further a huge hassel as I can drag, for example, Google Chrome. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Below, in this second image, you can see that the panel extends all the way down as well, creating a second wallpaper:

[image: Desktop Only]

The output of the command `ps -ef | grep -i panel` is

```
username    2084     1  0 12:24 ?        00:00:09 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
username    3821  3764  0 14:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i panel
```

Here is a list of things I have tried so far:

1. Restarting
2. Force restarting Unity (by activating/deactivating static application switcher in Compiz Config Utility)
3. Changing desktop background (you never know!)

---

System Specs

OS : Ubuntu 11.10
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965 Processor
Mem: 6 GB
GPU: Radeon HD 4670

Comment: obviously its a panel of some-sort... what is the output of `ps -ef | grep -i panel` ?  should give an indication of what panel is being run

Comment: @fossfreedom I'll edit the output into the question

Comment: well that's just bizarre ... +1 for a good question. The output didnt reveal any panels other than standard unity.  Have you installed anything extra lately?  XFCE related, gnome-panel, gnome-shell etc, etc?

Comment: No, I didn't even use ubuntu while it was in the new location. The only other thing I can say is that I have a dual monitor set up, but that was there before as well. Oh also, I have already tried restarting

Comment: Which is your video card? Can you go to the settings and disable one of the two monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On advice from [desgua](https://askubuntu.com/users/12943/desgua) I went to deactivate one of my monitors (via `catalyst`) and it displayed three monitors as being active. When I identified the monitors, it showed that I had monitors 2 and 3 set to my first and second monitor. My guess is that monitor 2 or 3 was occluding monitor 1. This might be one of those rare cases where a computer problem (not properly identifying the monitors) creates bizarre behaviour as opposed completely crashing the system.

In my case, I fixed it by removing the Display Port (DP) to DVI adapter. My guess is that since it was an active display port, it was confusing the video card into thinking there was a third monitor.

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;-)